# back referencing a table

Tags: back-referencing

I made a table and the codes is as follow:

```
\begin{table*}[t]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
 &
  \multicolumn{4}{c|}{TuckER} &
  \multicolumn{4}{c|}{TuckER-bk} &
  \multicolumn{4}{c|}{TuckER-bk-score} \\ \hline
 &
  Hits@10 &
  Hits@3 &
  Hits@1 &
  MRR &
  Hits@10 &
  Hits@3 &
  Hits@1 &
  MRR &
  Hits@10 &
  Hits@3 &
  Hits@1 &
  MRR \\ \hline
Symmetric &
  0.9588 &
  0.9570 &
  0.9453 &
  0.9512 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FE996B}0.9606 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{F8A102}0.9588 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{F56B00}0.9471 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{CE6301}0.9530 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}0.9597 &
  0.9570 &
  0.9462 &
  0.9520 \\ \hline
Asymmetric &
  0.1658 &
  0.1340 &
  0.1022 &
  0.1238 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FE996B}0.1692 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{F8A102}0.1358 &
  0.1055 &
  0.1270 &
  0.1691 &
  0.1357 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{F56B00}0.1089 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{CE6301}0.1284 \\ \hline
Both &
  0.6888 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{F8A102}0.6766 &
  0.6527 &
  0.6670 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{FE996B}0.6912 &
  0.6760 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{F56B00}0.6544 &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{CE6301}0.6677 &
  0.6830 &
  0.6667 &
  0.6480 &
  0.6600 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table*}
```

I want to be able to refer to it later on by writing: "referring to table ****" and I'm wondering how can i do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. At the moment we have to guess what packages etc you are using before we can compile your code. This said, try adding a `\label{mytable}` to table and a `\ref{mytable}` afterwards.

Comment: You will need a \caption before the \label will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add `\label{tbl:...}` inside your table like the code below

```
\begin{table*}[t]
\centering
\caption{Name of the Table here}
\label{tbl:name to use when you wants to refer}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    &  \\
    \hline
    &  \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table*}
```

Then where do you want to refer include `\ref{tbl:name to use when you wants to refer}`

```
Table \ref{tbl:name to use when you wants to refer} show us a ....
```

Also this kind of referenciation works well with all object that starts with `\begin`